# Microsoft graph API request.post with new version

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I was using this code earlier

```
CustomRequest request = new CustomRequest<>(String.format(sendMailUri, toEmail), getGraphServiceClient(),
List.of(new HeaderOption("Content-Type", "text/plain")), String.class);
request.post(encodedContent); //here encodedContent is a string
```

here the version used is 5.75.0 and the sendMailUri is ${app.graphAPI.sendMailUri:[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s/sendMail}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s/sendMail%7D)

I need to migrate this to latest version **6.4.0** how to do that , I know HeaderOption is depreciated I tried doing a lot of stuff but it was not working, Please help me out,

The main issue is that the request.post(string) does not send the string in the body , with the latest version , how do I implement this kind of strategy

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JAVA SDK, but at least .NET SDK has request adapter which allows to send request information

```
// init request information
RequestInformation ri = graphClient.users().byUserId("").sendMail().toPostRequestInformation(new SendMailPostRequestBody());
// remove header, by default it's set to application/json
ri.headers.remove("Content-Type");
// set header
ri.headers.add("Content-Type", "text/plain");
// set input stream, content
ri.content = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    
// get request adapter
RequestAdapter requestAdapter = graphClient.getRequestAdapter();
HashMap<String, ParsableFactory<? extends Parsable>> errorMapping = new HashMap<String, ParsableFactory<? extends Parsable>>();
    errorMapping.put("XXX", ODataError::createFromDiscriminatorValue);

// send request
requestAdapter.sendPrimitive(ri, errorMapping, Void.class);
```